# Animation problems in iOS

Tags: ios, animation

I used some animations in my application.Its working fine.But while calling another animation previous animation comes old position.How to resolve these kind of problems.

Here my code:

```
    CGRect frame = self.PickerView.frame;
    frame.origin.x=0;
    frame.origin.y=730;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    self.PickerView.frame=frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Are there any constraints in your view that might interfere with your animations ??

Comment: Are you this and the other animation within the same function? Could you provide more code?

Comment: no constraints is there